# Default token caching behaviour with ADAL library

Tags: azure, uwp, adal, azure-authentication

I have a UWP app using the ADAL authentication library and the default token cache.  When I log on the token appears to be saved and refreshed and I don't need to log in again, even if I close and reopen the app or restart the device, unless I manually clear the token cache.  This is the same for other users when testing with different accounts, devices and networks.

However some end users are seeing different behaviour where they are being asked to log in repeatedly, even when the app hasn't even been closed which suggests the token is not being refreshed automatically.  What I haven't been able to work out is what the difference is.  Has anyone else encountered this and know what might cause the difference in behaviour?

Comment: According your case without solid code base it would be very difficult to figure out. If possible share some more specific question. Hypothetical question has less possibility to be solved. So Would suggest you to update your question with some more details hope you understand...